# Is it OK to inherit from the C++11 smart pointers and override the relative operators?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), `std::shared_ptr` provides a full set of relative operators (==, !=, <, ...), but the semantics of comparison aren't specified. I assume they compare the underlying raw pointers to the referenced objects, and that std::weak_ptr and std::unique_ptr do the same.

For some purposes, I would prefer to have relative operators that order the smart pointers based on comparing the referenced objects (rather than the pointers to them). This is already something I do a lot, but with my own "dumb pointers" that behave mostly like raw pointers except for the relative operators. I'd like to do the same thing with the standard C++11 smart pointers too. So...

1. Is it OK to inherit from the C++11 smart pointers (shared_ptr, weak_ptr and unique_ptr) and override the relative operators?
2. Are there any sneaky issues I need to look out for? For example, are there any other methods I need to implement or use `using` for to ensure things work correctly?
3. For the ultimate in laziness, is there a library template available that will do this for me automatically?

I'm hoping this is an "of course you can do that, idiot!" kind of thing, but I'm a little uncertain because there are some classes in the standard library (containers like `std::map` at least) that you're not supposed to inherit from.

Comment: In general, it's not safe to inherit from anything who's destructor is not dynamic.  It can be and _is_ done commonly, you just have to be _really_ careful.

Comment: @Mooing Duck - OK, no late binding, which could be a problem for the destructor and elsewhere - makes sense. I don't think this is an issue for me, at least at the moment, but I will need to check. Perhaps it would be better to wrap a smart pointer as a member rather than to inherit.

Comment: Er, by "dynamic", I of course mean "virtual"

Comment: I think you're approaching this entirely the wrong way. If you have a pointer to something and you want to get that something, you dereference the pointer. Very basic idea applied here: want to compare to things pointed to by smart pointers? Dereference them. A smart pointer should act like a pointer. Write a comparison function like `dereference_compare` that does what you want, keep the concepts separate.

Comment: Perhaps another option is that your purpose (as you put it) accepts a comparator to be used for ordering. As an example, `std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>>` is different from `std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>, indirect_less<std::shared_ptr<T>>>>` (where `indirect_less` is left to the imagination of the reader, but should be obvious).

Comment: @GManNickG - that means you need to pass around that comparison as well as the relevant instances, and you run the risk of getting confused when there's two relevant orderings, applying the wrong ordering to the wrong instances. The usual solution to that issue is to package the two things together so they travel together, which is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @Steve314: *"of course you can do that*,  that is, get the behavior you want, but don't use inheritance *"idiot!"* (Just joking ;). You just need to define the operator you need with the semantics you want --Note: I am not claiming that his is a good idea, but is actually very simple to implement without abusing inheritance and the related problems.

Comment: @David - actually, "idiot" seems about right - I should have thought about inheritance issues, but didn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, it's not safe to inherit from anything who's destructor is not dynamic. It can be and is done commonly, you just have to be really careful.
Instead of inheriting from the pointers, I'd just use composition, especially since the number of members is relatively small.
You might be able to make a template class for this

```
template<class pointer_type>
class relative_ptr {
public:
    typedef typename std::pointer_traits<pointer_type>::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename std::pointer_traits<pointer_type>::element_type element_type;
    relative_ptr():ptr() {}
    template<class U>
    relative_ptr(U&& u):ptr(std::forward<U>(u)) {}
    relative_ptr(relative_ptr<pointer>&& rhs):ptr(std::move(rhs.ptr)) {}
    relative_ptr(const relative_ptr<pointer>& rhs):ptr(std::move(rhs.ptr)) {}

    void swap (relative_ptr<pointer>& rhs) {ptr.swap(rhs.ptr);}
    pointer release() {return ptr.release();}
    void reset(pointer p = pointer()) {ptr.reset(p);}
    pointer get() const {return ptr.get();}
    element_type& operator*() const {return *ptr;}
    const pointer_type& operator->() const {return ptr;}

    friend bool operator< (const relative_ptr& khs, const relative_ptr& rhs) const 
    {return std::less<element>(*lhs,*rhs);}
    friend bool operator<=(const relative_ptr& khs, const relative_ptr& rhs) const 
    {return std::less_equal<element>(*lhs,*rhs);}
    friend bool operator> (const relative_ptr& khs, const relative_ptr& rhs) const 
    {return std::greater<element>(*lhs,*rhs);}
    friend bool operator>=(const relative_ptr& khs, const relative_ptr& rhs) const 
    {return std::greater_equal<element>(*lhs,*rhs);}
    friend bool operator==(const relative_ptr& khs, const relative_ptr& rhs) const 
    {return *lhs==*rhs;}
    friend bool operator!=(const relative_ptr& khs, const relative_ptr& rhs) const 
    {return *lhs!=*rhs;}
protected:
    pointer_type ptr;
};
```

Obviously, the simplicity of the wrapper reduces you to the lowest common denominator for the smart pointers, but whatever.  They're not exactly complicated, you could make one for each of the smart pointer classes.

I will provide a warning that I don't like the way `==` works, since it may return true for two pointers to different objects.  But whatever.  I also haven't tested the code, it might fail for certain tasks, like attempting to copy when it contains a unique_ptr.

Comment: On "since it may return true for two pointers to different objects" - yes, but the same applies to normal instances. Think of these as proxies that just happen to also be smart pointers - being a pointer is more an implementation detail than the the provided abstraction.

Comment: I should have said this earlier, but there's also precedent in C++ for pointers that act like proxies and don't need to be dereferenced - the `&` references are also called self-dereferencing pointers.

Comment: A bit more convoluted than what is actually needed for this use case... :)

Answer (score 10):

The first thing, as others have already pointed out is that inheritance is not the way to go. But rather than the convoluted wrapper suggested by the accepted answer, I would do something much simpler: Implement your own comparator for your own types:

```
namespace myns {
struct mytype {
   int value;
};
bool operator<( mytype const& lhs, mytype const& rhs ) {
   return lhs.value < rhs.value;
}
bool operator<( std::shared_ptr<mytype> const & lhs, std::shared_ptr<mytype> const & rhs )
{
   // Handle the possibility that the pointers might be NULL!!!
   // ... then ...
   return *lhs < *rhs;
}
}
```

The *magic*, which is not really magic at all is Argument Dependent Lookup (aka. Koening Lookup or ADL). When the compiler encounters a function call it will add the namespace of the arguments to lookup. If the objects are the instantiation of a template, then the compiler will also add the namespaces of the types used to instantiate the template. So in:

```
int main() {
   std::shared_ptr<myns::mytype> a, b;
   if ( a < b ) {                       // [1]
      std::cout << "less\n";
   } else {
      std::cout << "more\n";
   }
}
```

In [1], and because `a` and `b` are objects *user defined types* <sup>(*)</sup> ADL will kick in and it will add both `std` and  `myns` to the lookup set. It will then find the standard definition of `operator<` for `std::shared_ptr` that is:

```
template<class T, class U>
bool std::operator<(shared_ptr<T> const& a, shared_ptr<U> const& b) noexcept;
```

And it will also add `myns` and add:

```
bool myns::operator<( mytype const& lhs, mytype const& rhs );
```

Then, after lookup finishes, overload resolution kicks in, and it will determine that `myns::operator<` is a better match than `std::operator<` for the call, as it is a perfect match and in that case non-templates take preference. It will then call your own `operator<` instead of the standard one.

This becomes a bit more convoluted if your type is actually a template, if it is, drop a comment and I will extend the answer.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> This is a slight simplification. Because `operator<` can be implemented both as a member function or a free function, the compiler will check inside `std::shared_ptr<>` for member `operator<` (not present in the standard) and friends. It will also look inside `mytype` for `friend` functions... and so on. But at the end it will find the right one.

Comment: I do this when appropriate but, as I pointed out in various comments, that's more things to pass around and possibly get mixed up. When you know that it's only correct to use the two things together, packaging them together ensures they travel together, and static typing provides extra checks. And while the name "pointer" might be misleading - this is more a kind of proxy, irrespective of the lack of networking issues - that doesn't mean packaging the functionality that way is a bad thing.

Comment: @Steve314 I really don't understand what you mean in your comment. Free functions in the namespace of the type are part of the same *interface* (in C++ the interface of an object is not limited to its members, due to ADL), and this solution is actually exploiting it. You only need to define in the same namespace as your type (and thus  in the same *interface*) your free function `operator<`. Many people are confused with OO meaning that you can only use member functions, but C++ is a richer language than that, and this is one of the cases where it shines, you can extend the library.

Comment: There is *nothing* to *pass around* in this solution. The operators are defined *once* in the namespace of your type, and they are available *everywhere*, *impicitly*, without any extra code at the place of call. It cannot be simpler than this.

Comment: Perhaps some context - the main reason this is an issue relates to a home-grown domain-specific language for dealing with AST nodes. One of the most basic facilities is support for multiple dispatch operations, but usefulness is limited by the use of raw pointers - doing transformations of ASTs, part-replacing and part-referencing, is definitely easier if you have some kind of garbage collection. Add support for smart pointers there, though, and it needs to be everywhere - including the polymorphic comparison generator which optionally provides a wrapped-pointer class.

Comment: why do you think one class can only be ordered one way? I have real-world cases with many different orderings. Those orderings have to be passed into code that supports any ordering, unless the data is wrapped along with the ordering information that applies to it.

Comment: @Steve314: There is no problem with doing a polymorphic comparator (well, there are, but they are unrelated to the question at hand). Just implement `operator<` as a virtual member function in your type, and provide the free function operators that dispatch to that member function: `virtual bool operator<(mytype const &);` as a member, then `bool operator<(std::shared_ptr<mytype> const& lhs, std::shared_ptr<mytype> const& rhs) { return *lhs < *rhs; }` (same as in the answer!)

Comment: @Steve314: *Why do I think one class can only be ordered one way?* I don't, but you are asking about the relational operators in `shared_ptr`, and there is only one `operator<` there. You can have as many orderings as you want, but they cannot all be `operator<` (well, they can taking different arguments, but then you only need to do the same thing you would be doing with the wrapper, although without the pitfalls of inheritance). That is the wrapper is not *needed* to provide the functionality, and it brings its own problems

Comment: polymorphic in this case means multiple dispatch, same as for multiple dispatch operations in general. I also get the advantages of a declarative code style.

Comment: I can declare many different wrappers based on the same basic type just by making the ordering a template parameter. And none of that prevents me from using a shared_ptr directly when I don't want to specify any ordering. Lots and lots of distinct types, with static checking making sure I don't confuse them, even though I'm referencing the same family of AST node classes.

Comment: @Steve314: There is no point in continuing the discussion. Just note that the wrapper approach does not answer the question (at least as stated), as it does not affect how `shared_ptr` compares. And I don't see how this is not an answer (I am not saying that you accept it or that this is the most appropriate design for your domain, but it is the answer to your question)

Comment: The wrapper is fine - it's prefer-composition-to-inheritance, but still keeping the reference and ordering together. A separate comparison is even *further* from what the question asks - I certainly agree that it should be said, but it's not the answer I need. I already use a separate comparison when it *is* the right solution and in fact by default that's all this code generator provides - the pointer-wrapping class is an optional extra.

Answer (score 4):

It's hazardous to inherit from any class that supports assignment and copy-construction, due to the risk of cutting a derived-class instance in half by accidentally assigning it to a base-class variable. This affects most classes, and is pretty much impossible to prevent, thus requiring vigilance on the part the class's users whenever they copy instances around.

Because of this, classes intended to function as bases usually shouldn't support copying. When copying is necessary, they should provide something like `Derived* clone() const override` instead.

The problem you are trying to solve is probably best addressed by leaving things as they are and providing custom comparators when working with such pointers.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> ii = …;
std::sort(begin(ii), end(ii),
          [](const std::shared_ptr<int>& a, const std::shared_ptr<int>& b) {
              return *a < *b;
          });
```