# Is it ok to subclass std::unique_ptr to transparently apply a custom deleter?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a certain type called `A` and I want to create multiple instances of `std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A *ptr)>` without explicitly passing the custom deleter every time. This is what I came up with:

```
void ADeleter(A *ptr) {
  // custom deletion logic
}

class APtr : public std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A *ptr)> {
  APtr() : APtr(nullptr) {}
  APtr(A *ptr) : std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A *ptr)>(ptr, ADeleter) {}
};
```

Is it safe (or even a good practice) to inherit from `std::unique_ptr` (or other smart pointer classes) in order to abstract construction with a custom deleter?

Comment: It does not answer your question, but what I already used is a custom default deleter: `namespace std {
 template<>
 class default_delete<A>
 {
 public:
  void operator()(A *p) { ADeleter(p); }
 };
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it OK to inherit from the C++11 smart pointers and override the relative operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539581/is-it-ok-to-inherit-from-the-c11-smart-pointers-and-override-the-relative-oper)

Comment: @werner doble check the standard; specializations of templates must not violate guarantees the standard places on itself.

Comment: @WernerHenze much safer to define that deleter outside `std` and provide an alias using it

Comment: Another (and in my opinion better) approach is to write a function that creates an appropriate object of type `std::unique_ptr`. This can be a simple function that takes an `A*`, or it can be a more complicated template function that constructs an `A` object (similar to `std::make_unique`).

Comment: @Caleth How would I do that? Can you give a short code snippet for my example code?

Comment: @WernerHenze see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem that might ( but should never ) arise is that because [`std::unique_ptr` doesn't have a `virtual` destructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.dtor) you shouldn't call `delete` on an object that has as different dynamic type than the pointer that refers to it (for example, deleting `APtr` through a pointer of `std::unique_ptr`) because that's UB which would be ironic since smart pointers are there to stop raw `new` and `delete` in the first place.

Other than that, I see no immediate issue with your way.

Comment: So, I'm safe as long as I don't use pointers to the smart pointer(`APtr *`)?

Comment: @ThiagodeArruda or arrays, directly or indirectly. And its pointers or arrays to the base class that are problematic, `std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A *ptr)>`

Comment: I believe you don't need the virtual as is doesn't make a difference in this VERY SPECIFIC case. That said, you can overload+delete the new operator to prevent the most easy mistakes against this (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)

Comment: @JVApen that's just adding more code to patch up a bad decision in the first place. `std::unique_ptr` has a template parameter *expressly for* this kind of usage

Answer (score 9):

No, the only classes in `std::` you should inherit from have virtual destructors. The design of most of `std` is template parameters as extension points, rather than subclassing.

What you want instead is

```
struct ADeleter {
    void operator()(A *ptr) {
      // custom deletion logic
    }
};

using APtr = std::unique_ptr<A, ADeleter>;
```

Comment: This is different though as it only allows one custom deleter per class, while there might be a need to use different deleters for the same class in different situations.

Comment: I think the first clause of your first sentence is much too strong for an upvote.  However, the suggestion to use a deleter class and a typedef is a much better one.

Comment: @Ivan : No.  `struct ADeleter2 { .... }; using APtr2 = std::unique_ptr<A, ADelete2>;` - The OP's implementation would already make the type of a pointer depend on the deleter in use.

Comment: @MartinBonner Oops, sorry for reason I though you proposed specialization of std::default_deleter. I guess I was reading comment above at the same time...

Comment: @Ivan : *I* am not proposing it - Caleth is proposing it (I just agree with him).

Comment: @Caleth: Classes in the iostream section of the standard library are meant to be inherited from.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley good point. I have weakened my initial stance

Answer (score 3):

You should not inherit from any class if you don't know if it has virtual destructor. Of course it can be done, but you have to be careful. It happens that `unique_ptr` don't have virtual destructor. So I suggest insted of inheritance use composition. Eg:

```
template<typename T>
class Ptr {
public:
    //TODO: here provide all needed member functions for Ptr class.
private:
    std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A *ptr)> ptr;
};
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this technique is that you have to redefine every single function of std::unique_ptr, is this worth the effort?

Answer (score 2):

Note that your question is opinion based.

If you are going to use pointer with specific deleter in many places - why not. I don't see any issues with that.

One recommendation I can give - use callable class as a deleter. Your `APtr` instance takes 2 pointers: one to an object, another one to a deleter function. If you use separate empty class for deleter, the result will only take 1 pointer and will be able to avoid additional function call on destruction.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to subclass, you can just use a `using` directive as follows:

```
class MyClass; //defined elsewhere
struct MyClass_deleter
{
    MyClass_deleter() = default;
    void operator()(MyClass* object)
    {
        // delete or clean up object here
    }
};
using MyClass_pointer = std::unique_ptr<MyClass, MyClass_deleter>;

// and use it as follows:
MyClass_pointer p(new MyClass());
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the case where he wants to use a generic function pointer as deletor

Comment: If the function pointer is the same every time, then you can just call it in the custom deleter. However if you need a dynamic function pointer each time, then you can just do `using MyClass_pointer = std::unique_ptr<MyClass, void(*)(MyClass*)>;` Note that one caveat to this is that you can no longer default init the unique pointer, or set it to nullptr with `ptr = nullptr`. The Op's example does not require a dynamic function pointer so this issue would not exist in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
template <typename T>                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
using unique_ptr_with_my_deleter = std::unique_ptr<T, my_deleter>;
//[...]
unique_ptr_with_my_deleter<int> u(new int(0));
```

Note that you need a C++11 compliant compiler for this to work.

Comment: I like this solution! But it's a bit incomplete, I have to make the leap and assume `my_deleter` is a function pointer type alias and that the function pointer/lambda can be passed to `unique_ptr_with_my_deleter<int>` s ctor, if it were more complete I would upvote :)

Comment: Paul B has a more complete example. Combine that with my templated using and your are good to go. :)